# Swift move view with keyboard

Tags: swift, uikeyboard

I am attempting to move my view up when the keyboard appears and back down when the keyboard is hidden.

The issue I have is that the heights seem to be different: KBH1 outputs 216, and KBH2 outputs 260.

This results in the view being moved down further than it was initially moved.

How would I rectify this?

```
extension UIViewController {

    func addKeyboardFunctions() {

        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboardEx))
       // tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillDisappear), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillAppear), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillAppear(_ notification: NSNotification) {

        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
                print("KBH: \(keyboardSize.height)")
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillDisappear(_ notification: NSNotification) {

        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
                self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
                print("KBH: \(keyboardSize.height)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the view controller embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: Hi no, its inside an embedded view

Comment: Does it contain a navigation bar?

Comment: nope, it doesnt

Comment: I'm asking about the navigation bar because the difference between the heights is 44 which is the height of the navigation bar. I believe it has something to do with that.

Comment: You can use Notification center to calculate the height of the keyboard going to be presented and handle your view. This gets a bit boring when you have loads of textViews and too many View Controllers. Although I personally don't prefer using pods, I would recommend https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager for this. Its quite simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`.

The notification will give you a begin frame and an end frame, so you can move your view accordingly. The end frame will be where the keyboard animation will end, so its final position. You should be using this.

I used to use this extension alot, I think it was for Swift 2

```
func getKeyboardHeight(notification: NSNotification) -> CGFloat {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    return keyboardSize.CGRectValue().height
}
```

You should be able to update that for Swift 4, but the most important part is to use the end frame and not the begin